# how to validate the edittext fields using switch case instead of if-else condition in android?

Tags: android

Previously i am using if else condition for checking the edit text field its working but i need to change into switch case.I am not getting to implement switch case inside my code.please tell me how to implement that in switch case.

```
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    /**
                     * Validation
                     */
                    if(tvStartLocation.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter start location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(tvEndLocation.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter end location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if(etStartOdometer.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter Trip Start Odometer reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
else
{
gotonextfraggment();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a switch-case construct in your case. In a switch-case, only one argument is matched with the case labels and if there is a match, that label is executed.

```
switch(arg) {
case "label1": 
case "label2":
.
.
.
default:
}
```

`arg` is tested with `label1`, `label2` and so on.

In your case, in every else-if, you are trying to test the equality of the text in different `EditText`s with `""`. So your `arg` changes in every else-if. Even if you try to implement switch-case, the `arg` of your switch-case will change continuously and you'll not be able to go any further. You cannot even do this:

```
switch("") {
case edittext1.getText():
case edittext2.getText();
.
.
.
default:
}
```

Because the case labels must be literals not variable values.

So it is impossible to implement switch-case for the problem that you are facing

In fact what you've done right now is the perfect way to do it.